# Чтение из C# Stream в коде C++

Tags: c#, c++, потоки-данных

Есть ли способ прочитать данные из Stream, созданного в C# в unmanaged C++ коде? Заранее благодарен)

Comment: Напрямую скорее всего не как. Создайте com интерфейс для стрима и передайте его в плюсы